# Importing module from github to react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cryptography, react-native

I am trying to implement this 'module' into my react native project.  This has already been rewritten for the browser so that it is completely in javascript.  I've been looking around and I can't seem to find exactly how to import it.  If this is a duplicate question or has an answer somewhere please link me to the other source! Thanks!

https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify

Answer (score 0):

Install it

`npm install --save crypto-browserify`

And require it in your code

`var crypto = require('crypto-browserify');`

Comment: so I did that originally and I keep getting `Invalid Directory /Users/node_modules/crypto-browserify` I went to the top directory of my project and installed it, I assumed thats where it should go right?

Comment: Yes, inside your project root, there should be a `node_modules` folder, inside that folder, there should exist a folder called `crypto-browserify`. Make sure that is the case.

Comment: yep, its there, checked that originally too.  Not sure whats going on